# NHibernate atomic record update

Tags: .net, nhibernate, transactions

What is the best way (if any) for atomic update record from a table without tranaction opening ?  I mean something like

```
 UPDATE Table_1 SET Value=Value+@Increment WHERE Id=@Id
```

Maybe it is possible by HQL or plane SQL from NHibernate...

Does last NHibernate version support update via HQL ?!
What about this statement?

```
  UPDATE Table_1 SET Value=Value+@Increment, @Result=1
        WHERE Id=@Id AND Value+@Increment<=@MaxLimit;SELECT @Result
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about transactions? If you don't specify a transaction explicitly one will be created implicitly by database itself.(e.g. Sql Server)

Comment: Yes, but what happen if I have already opened a transaction in NHibernate, and this update I want to proceed with more strict isolation level? So far, NHibernate doesn't have nested Transactions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL:

```
session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Entity1 SET Value=Value + :Increment WHERE Id=:Id")
    .SetParameter("Increment", 10)
    .SetParameter("Id", 5)
    .ExecuteUpdate()
```

SQL:

```
session.CreateSqlQuery("UPDATE Table_1 SET Value=Value + :Increment WHERE Id=:Id")
    .SetParameter("Increment", 10)
    .SetParameter("Id", 5)
    .ExecuteUpdate()
```

Comment: Do these statements achieve atomic update ? Should I wrap them in a transaction with appropriate isolation level?

Comment: you should wrap them in a transaction to make it clear, however when you dont NHibernate and/or the db will do it implicitly

Comment: What happen if I have already opened a transaction in NHibernate, and this update I want to proceed with more strict isolation level? So far, NHibernate doesn't have nested Transactions :(

Comment: then you have to open another session or implement nested transactions in NH (i did with a custom transactionfactory but its a bit work)